# Это будет Named Function Expression?

Tags: javascript

```js
function d(){

};

var v = d;
alert(v)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, в данном случае не *Named Function Expression*.

```
function d(){

};
```

В данном случае это [*FunctionDeclaration*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#prod-FunctionDeclaration). И от присваивания в переменную это не меняется.

Отличить *FunctionDeclaration* от *FunctionExpression* довольно просто: идентификатор *FunctionDeclaration* добавляется в текущий `LexicalEnvironment` что позволяет обращаться к нему вне функции, именно поэтому строка

```
var v = d;
```

не падает с ошибкой. В то же время имя *FunctionExpression* доступно *только внутри* этого выражение, например:

```js
var t = function d() {
  console.log(d);
};
t();
var v = d;
alert(v)
```

Comment: var t = function d() {
  console.log(d);
}; это будет  Named Function Expression. Имя NFE доступно только внутри функции если ее добавить в глобальный alert(d()) будет ошибка; также d() внутри функции нельзя переписать

Comment: @xes, не понимаю твое сообщение. _также d() внутри функции нельзя переписать_ - можно, просто будет бесконечная рекурсия в случае текущей функции

Comment: хотел сказать что я знал имя FunctionExpression можно использовать только внутри функции

Comment: @xes, Тогда почему у тебя возник твой вопрос, если в нем ты явно используешь имя вне функции

Comment: молодой глупый; и с замыканиями вопросы есть

Comment: вот здесь возник вопрос https://learn.javascript.ru/closures-usage

Comment: @xes, про замыкания уже куча вопросов и ответов тут была.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87870/discussion-between-grundy-and-xes).

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/928689/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%B2-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5?noredirect=1#comment1536917_928689

Comment: в первом примере var d = makeCounter() будет d = function counter() {
    return currentCount++;
  } как я понял это нет будет NFX правильно ?

Comment: NFX это  Named Function Expression.