# Как работает код счётчика, в котором одна функция возвращает другую функцию?

Tags: javascript

```js
function makeCounter() {
  var currentCount = 1;

  // возвращаемся к функции
  return function counter() {
    return currentCount++;
  }
};
var d = makeCounter()
```

В внутри функции makeCounter мы создаем функция counter в которой увеличиваем значение currentCount на 1 т.к так переменная currentCount не объявлена она ищет ее с помощью скрытого свойства [[scope]] которое есть у функции; переменная currentCount = 1; ее и увеличивает функция counter т.к. внутри функции переменная currentCount++  с постинкрементом  то значение увеличивается но возвращается старое значение. переменная d = 1; 
 а что происходит в этом коде ?

```js
function makeCounter() {
  var currentCount = 1;

  // возвращаемся к функции
  function counter() {
    return currentCount++;
  }

  // ...и добавляем ей методы!
  counter.set = function(value) {
    currentCount = value;
  };

  counter.reset = function() {
    currentCount = 1;
  };

  return counter;
}

var counter = makeCounter();
```

тут возвращается не функция а что ? не могу понять

Comment: В обоих случаях возвращается объекты функций. Во втором случае возвращается объект функции с именем counter. и с дополнительными свойствами

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow а мы создали глобальную переменную counter что получается var counter = counter; ?

Comment: Получается var counter = makeCounter();. Локальное имя counter внутри makeCounter не видимо за пределами этой функции.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow там же  return counter; и получается  counter = makeCounter(); в  глобальный counter вернется counter

Comment: Глобальный counter; будет ссылаться на локальный объект, который имел такое же имя.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow так можно что бы глобальное название было как и локальное ?

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow как я понимаю локальная переменная будет может брать значение глобальный, а на оборот нельзя

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow тут получается глобальная переменная ссылается на локальный объект

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Функция `makeCounter` - это конструктор счётчика. Вызывая ее будет возвращен новый объект счетчика. Здесь это видно

```
function makeCounter() {
    ...
    return counter;
}

var counter = makeCounter();
```

Сам возвращаемый `counter`, если посмотреть чуть выше, является функцией

```
function counter() {
    return currentCount++;
}
```

Иными словами, вызывая `makeCounter()` (создать счетчик) мы просто получаем на выходе другую функцию - `counter` (которая уже является самим счетчиком). Эту функцию теперь можно вызывать и при этом благодаря такой замечательной штуке как "замыкания" будет возвращена и инкрементирована локальная (локальная для `makeCounter`) переменная `currentCount`, содержащая текущее значение счетчика. Вызываем `counter` 1 раз - выход `1`. Вызываем десять подряд - последним значением получим `10`. Ничего сложного здесь

```js
function makeCounter() {
  var currentCount = 1;

  function counter() {
    return currentCount++;
  }

  return counter;
}

var counter = makeCounter();
console.log(counter());
counter()
counter()
counter()
counter()
counter()
counter()
counter()
counter()
console.log(counter());
```

Интереснее с вот этой частью

```
  counter.set = function(value) {
    currentCount = value;
  };

  counter.reset = function() {
    currentCount = 1;
  };
```

На самом деле ничего сложного здесь тоже нет. Стоит помнить что в JavaScript практически все является объектом. Функции в том числе. Поэтому равно как вы можете добавлять свойства объекту (`var o = {}; o.a = 1; o.b = 2;`), точно так же вы можете добавлять свойства и функции. Так почему бы не добавить нашему счетчику возможность начинать счет с чего-нибудь кроме единицы? Или сбрасываться в начальное состояние?

Так и сделано. Добавлены свойства (точнее сказать *методы*) объекту `counter` (да-да, именно объекту, ведь какая разница, что это функция?) с названиями `set` и `reset`, которые, соответственно, устанавливают счетчик в какое-нибудь значение, указанное Вами, или обнуляют (точнее "объединичивают") счетчик

```js
function makeCounter() {
  var currentCount = 1;

  function counter() {
    return currentCount++;
  }

  counter.set = function(value) {
    currentCount = value;
  };

  counter.reset = function() {
    currentCount = 1;
  };

  return counter;
}

var counter = makeCounter();
counter(); // 1
counter(); // 2
counter(); // 3

counter.reset(); // обнуляем, снова будет 1

counter(); // 1
counter(); // 2
counter(); // 3

counter.set(10); // а теперь возьмем и установим счетчик в 10

counter(); // 10
counter(); // 11
counter(); // 12

// Проверяем?
console.log(counter()); // должно быть 13
```

Comment: ок спасибо позже ознакомлюсь если не возражаете :))

Comment: в глобальную переменную var counter = makeCounter(); makeCounter() возвращает counter; получается var counter = counter и это нормально ?

Comment: @xes да не заморачивайтесь вы с именами переменных. Называйте как хотите. То, что имена одинаковые - абсолютно неважно, поскольку у этих переменных разные области видимости.